# DRF user creation with one-to-one relation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have made a model and serializers for User and additional ones for their profile (additional info).

Model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    users = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nickname
```

Serializers

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username']
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    users = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['users', 'nickname']
```

It works fine for displaying it all out, but now i want to make it so i could create a new `User` with POST request AND also automatically assign a new empty or default `Profile` instance for that same `User`. DRF doesn't allow me to do that directly from `Profile` model API. Should i create a `views.py` function which will create a user and also create `Profile` for it separately or there's a built-in methods for that, so User then can update their `Profile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to override the create function of your serializer. Also, you dont really need two serializers for this purpose. Something like this will do the job for you, (change according to your fields):

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """
    Serializer for user details
    """
    username = serializers.CharField()
    nickname = serializers.CharField()
    bio = serializers.CharField()
    first_name = serializers.CharField()
    last_name = serializers.CharField()
    email = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(
            username=validated_data["username"],
            email=validated_data["email"]
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data["password"])
        user_id = user.save()
        Profile.objects.create(
            user_id=user.id,
            nickname=validated_data["nickname"],
            bio=validated_data["bio"]
        )
        return validated_data
```

Comment: That's great, didn't knew i could edit the default functions. Thanks

Comment: Beauty of django is you can simply override things to work the way you want to. You just need to find a way for it.